# Do I need a "full differential" ADC? (if sensor voltage input range = 0.8V to 4.3V)

Tags: voltage, adc, differential, input, variable

I am not using potentiometer like most video or print online.
I am using bike grip/hall throttle, its range is 0.8V to 4.3V.

**Instead of:**

[0V = 000 ADC value] [5V = 255 ADC value]

**I want:**

[0.8V = 000 ADC value] [4.3V = 255 ADC value]

**What ADC do I need ??? How do I wire???**

*NOTE: Before leaving comment...the video I reference below shows the author achieving 2V-3V (start video at 2:46). I want 0.8V to 4.3V. If you don't have people skills or can't answer my question...please don't leave comments... I am not as smart as some of you.*

[ My research so far ]:

(1)
How to use Differential Voltage Input ADC's

- Author uses ic chip ADC0831
- Video includes schematic
- Start video at 2:46 !!
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wT6nRqV7Vc&t=117s

(2)
What is a differential ADC?

- Forum quote/Peter Gibson:
- A differential ADC shifts the lower reference from 0V to some other value - either a user input - - - on a second analog input, or a internal reference.
  [What is a differential ADC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/what-is-a-differential-adc)

Comment: You are shouting. Why wouldn't you just use a 10 or 12 bit ADC and scale the reading digitally?

Comment: In a word, no. Because what you are asking for has nothing to do with a differential ADC, in concept or in hardware. I am quite sure you do not know what a differential ADC actually does.

Comment: Go with what Spehro Pefany said.  Your signal is not differential. It sounds to me like some form of variable resistor.  If your using a microcontroller with a builtin ADC, use that one with calibration.

Comment: STOP SHOUTING AT US.

Comment: @SolarMike Please exclude me from your us. I'm not so sensitive.

Comment: @Huisman you can be excluded from whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most reasonable approach to reach the desired reading is to offset them by software.

On a 5V, 8-bit ADC, each value is 0.019V. So a reading of 0.8V would be "42". You can add this in software to subtract, for example if you are reading 0.8V, you would get 42 -42 = 0

A Single Ended ADC can measure a voltage on its input terminal between ground and Vref. For example: To measure a light sensors output, or a potentiometer output, a Single-Ended ADC is used.

A differential ADC is used to measure the difference between the terminals, for example: To measure current, usually a sense resistor is used and a differential ADC is connected to both resistor pins, to measure the voltage drop over the resistor.

For your application a standard single-ended OR Differential will work. If you use a differential one, just connect the negative input to ground.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using an Arduino environment, the map() function would be very useful.